# Understanding the function of this particular 9 patch image

Tags: android, png, ionic-framework, nine-patch

please check out this [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/make-9patched-splash-ionic):

This is a tool to generate `9 patch images` for splash screen in [ionic framework](http://ionicframework.com/), now from my understanding of `9 patch image` , if there is a black line , it means that the image is allowed to stretch in that region.

However in the tool dots are mentioned.

[image]

Can you please help me understand what that means. My splash screen used to be a single png file with a logo at the center but was a bit distorted, Now after I have implemented `9 patched images`, the distortion has gone but the logo has become quite small.

Any idea why this is happening ?

Comment: Why not use the ionic cli command: `ionic resources`, see this blog post http://blog.ionic.io/automating-icons-and-splash-screens/

Comment: @MarkVeenstra because the splash screens created from that command appear distorted in some android phones, like nexus 5, moto x etc

Comment: These dots may represent *very short lines*. In this case only the Ghastly Green Border can be stretched (and, by extension, the little pinky corner rectangles). The white area will stay the same size. Without an image of your logo and how you indicated the 9 patches I can't tell if you did it right.

Comment: @Jongware Sir my logo is a small one in the white area which doesnt get streched, now my logo also has a bacground image pattern which gets streched after I use this method, any idea how to 9 patch such images ?

Comment: Without an image of your logo and how you indicated the 9 patches I can't tell if you did it right. But the entire idea is that you indicate which areas are *allowed to stretch*, so it should not have been a surprise for you that some parts did.